# Unity2D How to ignore collisions with specific objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using an animated sprite to collide and delete an enemy sprite. The enemy sprite disappears when it hits my floor (sprite) also. (All have rigidbody2D). How do I get the enemy sprite to ignore the floor and everything else except the animated sprite?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D()
    {
        if (gameObject.tag.Equals("Enemy"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Edit** > **Project Settings** > **Physics** (or **Physics2D**) and edit the Layer Collision Matrix:

[image: Layer Collision Matrix]

Comment: @LordMalicious needs a bit more rep before they can upvote, but this answer is correct and should be accepted.